# How to create a new variable that assigns consecutive numbers for cases with same combination of values on other variables

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 110 participants who answered the same questionnaire in multiple sessions within three timeframes. The number of sessions per timeframe differs within and between participants.

I need a new variable that assigns consecutive numbers to the sessions a participant X completed the questionnaire within the timeframe Y from 1 to (number of sessions participant X completed the questionnaire within timeframe Y).

Example: I have

```
participant  timeframe    date                           
        1     1     2021-04-30 09:12:00
        1     1     2021-04-30 10:03:00
        1     1     2021-05-02 09:20:00
        2     1     2021-04-30 13:00:00
        2     1     2021-05-02 12:13:00
        1     2     2021-05-05 08:34:00
        1     2     2021-05-06 14:15:00
        2     2     2021-05-05 07:12:00
        2     2     2021-05-05 14:13:00
        2     2     2021-05-08 15:22:00
```

I need:

```
 participant   timeframe        date                session per timeframe    
        1         1      2021-04-30 09:12:00                  1
        1         1      2021-04-30 10:03:00                  2
        1         1      2021-05-02 09:20:00                  3
        2         1      2021-04-30 13:00:00                  1
        2         1      2021-05-02 12:13:00                  2
        1         2      2021-05-05 08:34:00                  1
        1         2      2021-05-06 14:15:00                  2
        2         2      2021-05-05 07:12:00                  1
        2         2      2021-05-05 14:13:00                  2
        2         2      2021-05-08 15:22:00                  3
```

Hope that somebody can help! Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a tidyverse approach using row_number():

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

dat <- tribble(~participant,  ~timeframe,    ~date,                           
        1,     1,     "2021-04-30 09:12:00",
        1,     1,     "2021-04-30 10:03:00",
        1,     1,     "2021-05-02 09:20:00",
        2,     1,     "2021-04-30 13:00:00",
        2,     1,     "2021-05-02 12:13:00",
        1,     2,     "2021-05-05 08:34:00",
        1,     2,     "2021-05-06 14:15:00",
        2,     2,     "2021-05-05 07:12:00",
        2,     2,     "2021-05-05 14:13:00",
        2,     2,     "2021-05-08 15:22:00") %>% 
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date))

dat %>% 
  group_by(participant, timeframe) %>% 
  mutate(session = row_number())

#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#> # Groups:   participant, timeframe [4]
#>    participant timeframe date                session
#>          <dbl>     <dbl> <dttm>                <int>
#>  1           1         1 2021-04-30 09:12:00       1
#>  2           1         1 2021-04-30 10:03:00       2
#>  3           1         1 2021-05-02 09:20:00       3
#>  4           2         1 2021-04-30 13:00:00       1
#>  5           2         1 2021-05-02 12:13:00       2
#>  6           1         2 2021-05-05 08:34:00       1
#>  7           1         2 2021-05-06 14:15:00       2
#>  8           2         2 2021-05-05 07:12:00       1
#>  9           2         2 2021-05-05 14:13:00       2
#> 10           2         2 2021-05-08 15:22:00       3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use `rleid`:

```
library(data.table)
df %>%
  group_by(participant, timeframe) %>%
  mutate(session_per_timeframe = rleid(date))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   participant, timeframe [4]
   participant timeframe date                session_per_timeframe
         <dbl>     <dbl> <dttm>                              <int>
 1           1         1 2021-04-30 09:12:00                     1
 2           1         1 2021-04-30 10:03:00                     2
 3           1         1 2021-05-02 09:20:00                     3
 4           2         1 2021-04-30 13:00:00                     1
 5           2         1 2021-05-02 12:13:00                     2
 6           1         2 2021-05-05 08:34:00                     1
 7           1         2 2021-05-06 14:15:00                     2
 8           2         2 2021-05-05 07:12:00                     1
 9           2         2 2021-05-05 14:13:00                     2
10           2         2 2021-05-08 15:22:00                     3
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer

```
data %>% group_by(grp = data.table::rleid(participant)) %>%
  mutate(session = row_number())

# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   grp [4]
   participant timeframe date                  grp session
         <int>     <int> <chr>               <int>   <int>
 1           1         1 2021-04-30 09:12:00     1       1
 2           1         1 2021-04-30 10:03:00     1       2
 3           1         1 2021-05-02 09:20:00     1       3
 4           2         1 2021-04-30 13:00:00     2       1
 5           2         1 2021-05-02 12:13:00     2       2
 6           1         2 2021-05-05 08:34:00     3       1
 7           1         2 2021-05-06 14:15:00     3       2
 8           2         2 2021-05-05 07:12:00     4       1
 9           2         2 2021-05-05 14:13:00     4       2
10           2         2 2021-05-08 15:22:00     4       3
```